# Entity framework core. Необходимо получить несколько объектов из бд, начиная от записи с выбранным Id

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

Необходимо получить несколько записей из базы данных. Первичный ключ таблицы является строкой. Как мне получить определенное количество записей начиная со строки с выбранным идентификатором?

Comment: Что значит "начиная с"? Порядок выдачи строк базой не гарантируется. Просто сортируйте по нужному признаку и берите нужное количество записей, типа: `.OrderBy(...).SkipWhile(...).Take(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще эта затея выглядит довольно сомнительной, так как непонятно, что значит "начиная со строки с выбранным идентификатором". Если вас интересуют именно строки, вставленные после строки с выбранным идентификатором, то проблема в том, что строковый первичный ключ не позволит определить, что вставлено раньше, а что позже за исключением случаев, когда в нём заложена дополнительная информация, например, он представляет собой строковое представление даты или целочисленного идентификатора (но тогда возникает вопрос, зачем вообще использовать строковый идентификатор, а не целочисленный).

Добиться поставленной задачи можно было бы если бы ваш первичный ключ имел целочисленный тип данных с модификатором `IDENTITY`, который гарантирует последовательное и автоматическое увеличение первичного ключа. Тогда всё можно было бы свести к простой конструкции вида

```
var data = MyContext.MyDbSet.Where(x => x.Id >= myId).Take(count);
```

которая преобразовалась бы в sql наподобие

```
SELECT TOP (count) [Columns]
FROM [dbo].[TableName] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] >= myId
```

и вернула бы `count` строк, добавленных в таблицу после добавления строки с идентификатором `myId`. Вообще конечно вы можете использовать этот код и в вашем случае, но тогда он вернёт не строки, добавленные после строки с идентификатором `myId`, а строки, идентификатор которых больше или равен `myId` согласно способу сравнения строк.